# Kubernetes with Metallb and Traefik behind OpenVPN

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, openvpn, metallb

I have a Kubernetes cluster installed on a bare metal server, I have installed Metallb for external load balancer and Traefik for reverse proxy engine, this cluster is behind an OpenVPN with subnet `10.1.0.0/24`, the ip for the server is `10.1.0.1`

For the Metallb I assign ip `10.1.1.0/24` for the pool, so the Traefik LoadBalancer ip is `10.1.1.1`

I also have my own Domain Name Server that will be pushed to the server when connected to the VPN

If I create a domain for one of my app inside the Kubernetes Cluster, to what IP should I point my Domain so that I can access my app through the domain from other server that are also connected to the VPN?

I think I misconfigured something but I got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point the domain to the Traefik Loadbalancer IP, which is ‘10.1.1.1’ in your case. The IP address which you have shared is an external IP provided by Metallb.

When the client connects to the application using the domain; the DNS resolution process will resolve the domain to the Traefik LB IP. The traffic will be forwarded to the Traefik LB IP, which will route the traffic to the appropriate service and the pod in your Kubernetes cluster based on the rules defined in your Trafik. Please check this Here is the blog posted by Peter Gillich for your [reference](https://pgillich.medium.com/setup-on-premise-kubernetes-with-kubeadm-metallb-traefik-and-vagrant-8a9d8d28951a).

Comment: I have tried pointing the domain to `10.1.1.1`, but I think because all the server are behind a VPN, the other server can't reach it

do I need to add something in the VPN configuration?

Comment: Try these troubleshooting steps; 1. Check VPN configuration to allow traffic between the servers. 2. VPN connectivity whether servers could communicate with each other over the VPN; try oinging IP address of the server. 3. Check DNS configuration and firewall or if you have multiple servers try with VPN gateway.